# Can I retrieve text messages if I backed up to wrong date?

Tags: ios

I backed up to an old date in icloud and lost recent text messages when upgraded to ios 7.  Can I somehow find those more recent text messages?  If not, can the Apple store find them?

Comment: You mean you restored to an older backup after the upgrade to iOS 7?

Comment: When restoring from iCloud, did you choose the last version available?

Comment: Or do you have a recent iTunes back-up?

Answer (score 1):

If you did not have a recent back-up of your device (on iCloud or iTunes), there is *no way*, after a restore, you can get your SMSs back.